# restarting windows 11 to boot ubuntu 22.04.3 stuck on /dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, x/x files, x/x blocks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-11

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 alongside my Windows 11, and both operating systems boot fine individually. However, I encounter an issue when restarting from Windows to Ubuntu through the GRUB page. After selecting Ubuntu, it gets stuck indefinitely on this message:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, x/x files, x/x blocks
```

then i have to hold the power button to restart the laptop and enter ubuntu without an issue.

This problem occurs specifically when transitioning from Windows to Ubuntu, not when directly starting the laptop and choose Ubuntu from GRUB boot menu (even rebooting from ubuntu to windows works fine! ).

Attempts to resolve this include disabling fast boot and secure boot from both BIOS and Windows settings, yet the issue persists. Any insights or solutions to overcome this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Note: it seems like a crash since the cursor stops flickering it would be great to know how can i check the boot crash reason

Thanks!

Comment: List logged boots with `journalctl --list-boots` and then choose the number on the lift based on the timestamp that you recall had that problem and inspect the logs for that boot by using it's reference number (*either a `0` or a minus number like `-1`,`-2` ... etc.*) like e.g. so `journalctl -b -1` ... See if you can spot something out of the norm ... Also check the output of `sudo cat /var/log/boot.log*`

Comment: thank you
but i didn't found anything useful there.
is there something specific i need to look for ?